# Swift - Calling method from a closure while omitting arguments

Tags: swift, rx-swift

While subscribing to a subject, I am calling a method that takes in the value received from the subject. I came across a syntax in the code where that value is not passed in explicitly as an argument, nor the method was forced to use **self** keyboard before calling it.
Q1. Could someone please shed some light on this syntax?
Q2. Does this mean that there is a strong reference to self?

```
.subscribe(onNext: updateNewNumber(from:))
```

Just to reiterate, the subject is passing simply an integer.

Comment: The updateNewNumber method will be called by subscribe which will passe the from: parameter. Subscribe may use whatever it is accessible to it as parameter. The case you would have to use the ‘number in’ syntax would be if you put the code of updateNewNumber there as a closure between {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: It's called "point-free style". It's a way of passing a function around as a variable.

If `updateNewNumber(from:)` is a method, then it's the same as:

```
.subscribe(onNext: { self.updateNewNumber(from: $0) })
```

If it's a free function, then it's the same as:

```
.subscribe(onNext: { updateNewNumber(from: $0) })
```

Q2: There is not a strong reference to the *method*, but there is a strong reference to `self` as indicated by the above.